# How to parse a resource for the ID in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, uri

I have a relative URI / resource:

```
"/v1/threads/110408889879497140/"
```

I want to just parse out the ID (the final number in this string).

Hoping something other than regex :)

Comment: split on '/' and take the last element of the array?

Comment: @Matt is correct but why would you avoid a Regex? methods like `#scan` could perform this task fairly easily as well.

Comment: Don't fear regular expressions. They're very handy if you know how to use them effectively, and every bit of practice helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL is just a protocol designation followed by a file path, so use [`File.basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/File.html#method-c-basename) which was designed to work with file paths:

```
File.basename("/v1/threads/110408889879497140/")
# => "110408889879497140"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "/v1/threads/110408889879497140/"
a.split('/').last
```

you can also do it with rpartition:

```
"/v1/threads/110408889879497140/".rpartition('threads/').last.chop
```

Use scan with regex:

```
a.scan(/\d{5,}/)
```

If you want to isolate numbers in a string without regex, you can use the fact that numbers have ASCII range from 48 to 57 and do something like:

```
a = "/v1/threads/110408889879497140/"
a.each_char{ |c| a.delete!(c) unless c.ord.between?(48, 57) }
p a #=> 1110408889879497140
```

Comment: Your last example has three initial 1's.

Comment: that's because of the v1. I'd recommend the scan method as the most reliable one.